# Moment.js US state codes get local time?

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to pass a US state code moment.js like TX, AZ, FL  and have it give me the local time there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used moment.js. But i got the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var states = {
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AS": "American Samoa",
    "AZ": "Arizona",
    "AR": "Arkansas",
    "CA": "California",
    "CO": "Colorado",
    "CT": "Connecticut",
    "DE": "Delaware",
    "DC": "District Of Columbia",
    "FM": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
    "FL": "Florida",
    "GA": "Georgia",
    "GU": "Guam",
    "HI": "Hawaii",
    "ID": "Idaho",
    "IL": "Illinois",
    "IN": "Indiana",
    "IA": "Iowa",
    "KS": "Kansas",
    "KY": "Kentucky",
    "LA": "Louisiana",
    "ME": "Maine",
    "MH": "Marshall Islands",
    "MD": "Maryland",
    "MA": "Massachusetts",
    "MI": "Michigan",
    "MN": "Minnesota",
    "MS": "Mississippi",
    "MO": "Missouri",
    "MT": "Montana",
    "NE": "Nebraska",
    "NV": "Nevada",
    "NH": "New Hampshire",
    "NJ": "New Jersey",
    "NM": "New Mexico",
    "NY": "New York",
    "NC": "North Carolina",
    "ND": "North Dakota",
    "MP": "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "OH": "Ohio",
    "OK": "Oklahoma",
    "OR": "Oregon",
    "PW": "Palau",
    "PA": "Pennsylvania",
    "PR": "Puerto Rico",
    "RI": "Rhode Island",
    "SC": "South Carolina",
    "SD": "South Dakota",
    "TN": "Tennessee",
    "TX": "Texas",
    "UT": "Utah",
    "VT": "Vermont",
    "VI": "Virgin Islands",
    "VA": "Virginia",
    "WA": "Washington",
    "WV": "West Virginia",
    "WI": "Wisconsin",
    "WY": "Wyoming"
  };
  //Washington 13.00 WA
  //Texas 12:00 TX
  //Colorado 11  CO
  var state = states["SD"];
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': state + ', us'
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var lati = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longi = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      // alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
      var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=" + lati + "," + longi + "&timestamp=0";

      $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
          if (i == 'timeZoneId') {
            var localtime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
              timeZone: field
            })

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localtime;
          }
        });
      });

    } else {
      alert("Something got wrong " + status);
    }
    var i = 1;
  });

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1 id="demo"></h1>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
var a = moment.tz("2015-09-04 11:55", "America/Toronto");
```

You can refer [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: For Alabama, this seemed closest to me: moment().tz('America/Matamoros').format()